# Compute the number of distinct values in col2 for each distinct value in col1 in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
          SchoolID=c("A","A","B","B","C","D"),
          Country=c("XX","XX","XX","YY","ZZ","ZZ"))
```

which gives me this data:

```
    SchoolID    Country
1   A           XX
2   A           XX
3   B           XX
4   B           YY
5   C           ZZ
6   D           ZZ
```

I would like to know for each SchoolID whether Country is uniquely assigned, by looking, for each distinct value of SchoolID, the number of distinct values of Country. So I would like to obtain this kind of table:

```
SchoolID   NumberOfCountry
A          1
B          2
C          1
D          1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aggregate(Country ~ SchoolID, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Or

```
tapply(df$Country, df$SchoolID, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Or

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df)[, .(NumberOfCountry = length(unique(Country))), by = SchoolID]
```

Or with [v >1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
setDT(df)[, .(NumberOfCountry = uniqueN(Country)), by = SchoolID]
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(SchoolID) %>% 
  summarise(NumberOfCountry = n_distinct(Country))
```

Comment: Thank you. The tapply solution worked. However, the aggregate solution returned an error. And so did the data.table solution (apparently setDT function is not defined). I do not have access to the dplyr package.

Comment: The `aggregate` solution shouldn't give an error. Did you copy/paste the code as is? In the `data.table` solution you can replace `setDT(df)` with `as.data.table(df)`. Which R version do you use? You weren't able to install `dplyr`  using `install.packages("dplyr")`?

Comment: I am on a company server running R 3.0.1. The data.table package is version 1.8.8. The error is `Error: could not find function "setDT"`. `dplyr` is not available for my version of R.

Comment: So replace `setDT(df)` with `as.data.table(df)`. What error the `aggregate` function gives you?

Comment: When doing the replacement with `as.data.table(df)`, I get `Error in UseMethod("as.data.table") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.data.table' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: Can you show the whole code? Did you do `as.data.table(df)[, list(NumberOfCountry = length(unique(Country))), by = SchoolID]` ?

Comment: `library(data.table)`

`as.data.table(df)[, list(NumberOfCountry = length(unique(Country))), by = SchoolID]`

Comment: I think you need to reinstall your R and the packages. You have very srtange errors

Comment: Thank you for your effort David, unfortunately I do not have admin rights on the server running R.

Answer (score 1):

One approach, which does not rely on third-party libraries:

```
> as.data.frame(rowSums(table(df[!duplicated(df), ]), na.rm=T))
  rowSums(table(df[!duplicated(df), ]), na.rm = T)
A                                                1
B                                                2
C                                                1
D                                                1
```

Comment: This is a very convoluted approach. Why not simply `data.frame(table(unique(df)$SchoolID))`?

Comment: Ananda, your suggestion gives me an error, that `Error in unique.default(df) : unique() applies only to vectors`.

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
select School,count(Country)
from(
select distinct School,Country
from tbl_stacko) temp
group by School
```

Comment: You could modify your solution to be valid in the `[r]` tag: `library(sqldf)` ; `sqldf("select SchoolID, count(Country) from(select distinct SchoolID, Country from df) temp group by SchoolID")`